# Salvar UserID de un usuario logueado en una colmna especifica de el Data Base

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Necesito salvar el ID del usuario que ha hecho login en la columna de nombre "CreatedBy", pero no logro escribir la query correcta.

Cada que viene creada una entidad **"FitnessGoal"** se salvara en el DB los datos de dicha identidad mas el ID del Usuario:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Goal,StartDate,FinishDate,Weight")] FitnessGoals fitnessGoals)
        {

            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.FitnessGoals.Add(fitnessGoals);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(fitnessGoals);
        }
```

Clase **FitnessGoal**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FitnessWebApplication.Models
{
    [Table("FitnessGoals")]
    public class FitnessGoals
    {
        /*public List<string> Goals ;

        public FitnessGoals() { this.Goals.Add("Bulk"); this.Goals.Add("Cut"); }*/

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Goal { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }

        public int Weight { get; set; }

        public enum Goals
        {
            Bulk,
            Cut
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que ya tienes al objeto `fitnessGoals` con sus propiedades definidas desde el cliente, internamente lo que hace falta es agregar una propiedad más, por lo tanto, aquí el código:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    //La siguiente línea determina a la propiedad CreatedBy y le asigna el valor del usuario.
    fitnessGoals.CreatedBy = user; //Asumiendo que esta variable contiene el UserId.
    //Esta línea se encarga de agregar el elemento a la tabla FitnessGoals.
    db.FitnessGoals.Add(fitnessGoals);
    //Finalmente Entity Framework guarda los cambios en la base de datos.
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Parece funcionar pero ahora tengo una excepcion: System.NotImplementedException: Operacion o metodo no implementado.

Comment: ¿Dónde?¿En qué línea?

Comment: en la linea 23 del IndentityModel:                                                  public static implicit operator string(ApplicationUser v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //aqui
        }

Comment: @fredyfx, por favor [edit] la respuesta para agregar una explicación al código que colocaste.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave claro mi estimado, ahora mismo le agrego unos comentarios :D